# will NSFileSystemFileNumber in iOS always be unique?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, attributes, nsfilemanager

When using attributesOfItemAtPath:error:, is NSFileSystemFileNumber always guaranteed to be unique for the device?

For example, I have a file with a certain NSFileSystemFileNumber, but a few days later I delete this file. If I create another file later on, is it possible that this new file can ever re-use the other file's NSFileSystemFileNumber, or will the NSFileSystemFileNumber **always** be unique?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[NSFileManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> *NSFileSystemFileNumber*
>
> The key in a 
>   file attribute dictionary whose value
>   indicates the file's filesystem file
>   number. The corresponding value is an
>   NSNumber object containing an unsigned
>   long. The value corresponds to the
>   value of st_ino, as returned by
>   stat(2).

```
man 2 stat
```

> ino_t    st_ino;    /* inode's number */

So this is an inode number. I believe inode can be reused by filesystem after original file is deleted.

Comment: Thanks, looks like "u_long   st_gen;    /* file generation number */" gets incremented if/when the inode is reused, but that's only available to the superuser apparently. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The NSFileSystemFileNumber is just the file's inode number. It's unique to the file while the file exists, but once the file is gone, it could be reused at any time.

Comment: Thanks Chuck! Looks like hoha beat ya to it. :)